# Dynamically filling a navigation menu using a database

Tags: jquery

I am currently building a web store from the ground up. This web store will contain hundreds of different types of products related to the company I work for.

I am currently working on the filter menu where the user can click different categories to filter down the product list that is shown to them. Since there are hundreds of different categories the user can choose from, I am using a database to dynamically load this list. The table with this information has 3 columns. categoryID, name, and parentID.

My issue is I cannot find a good way to turn this into a multi-level navigation menu. The end result will be nested ul's that allow the user to click the parent li to slidetoggle a hidden ul. Clicking the li containing "vegetable" will slidetoggle the ul containing li's carrot and celery.

Here is the jsfiddle of the navigation menu working, I just can't think of a good way to dynamically fill the ul and li's.

HTML

```
<ul class='top-level'>
    <li class='top-level-child'>Fruit</li>
    <ul class='second-level'>
      <li class='second-level-child'>Apple</li>
    </ul>
  <li class='top-level-child'>Vegetable</li>
    <ul class='second-level'>
      <li class='second-level-child'>Carrot</li>
        <ul class='third-level'>
          <li class='third-level-child'>Diced</li>
          <li class='third-level-child'>Chopped</li>
                    <li class='third-level-child'>Julienned</li>
                </ul>
      <li class='second-level-child'>Celery</li>
        <ul class='third-level'>
          <li class='third-level-child'>Diced</li>
          <li class='third-level-child'>Chopped</li>
                    <li class='third-level-child'>Julienned</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    <li class='top-level-child'>Snack</li>
        <ul class='second-level'>
      <li class='second-level-child'>Twinkie</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zdd1b79u/

Edit: Forgot to mention, the database information is in json form.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: advice: learn javascript

Comment: super useful, thanks.

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: I'd would go by learning recursive functions. Look your estructure looks like a tree. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170835/recursive-function-to-create-a-tree#answer-40171055